# Can't override service exe file after service was stopped

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service, service

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I stopped my service and trying to override the exe file to update it, but it gives me access denied exception. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Is the process still running?  Do you have rights to overwrite the file?

Comment: Services windows show process as stopped. I do have rights, since I trying to do it under administrative credentials.

Answer (score 2):

The [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) program can tell you which process has a file open. It's under the 'Find' menu.